# Dismissed improvement request are deleted?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I can't see [my improvement request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/1113) anymore, it may have something to do with the fact that a [later draft removed it](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/16305). Shouldn't the author (myself) and privileged users being able to see even deleted... umm... I really don't know how to call them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple layered bugs here.

It is intentional that the "normal" link for improvement requests actually links to all requests on a topic.

It's not intentional that it 404s if the topic is deleted.  That's now fixed, it'll send you to the "show me the deleted version"-page now.

When browsing from your user profile it was also not intentional that links to improvement requests continued to point to the topic after they were handled.  Now if an improvement request as been handled, links on your profile will point to the draft that handled it.

For example, on my profile:

[image]

now [points here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/draft/77).

Comment: > "It is intentional that the "normal" link for improvement requests actually links to all requests on a topic."
on *a* topic or on *all* topics? here I clicked to see 1 improvement request for c++'s topic `std::vector`, but see all imp reqs on c++ http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b?tab=needsimprovement&topicId=511. actually you can see "1 Improvements Requested for std::vector" but follows the full list of ~12 that appear when you do c++ -> dashboard -> need improvement.