# Should we have separate topics for different versions?

Tags: discussion, documentation

In the C documentation tag, there are currently two topics for *Undefined behavior*, one for all versions and one for the current standard only, which has examples that are specific to that standard. This question is not about that specific instance, but for this problem in general.

In such cases, should the examples be moved to the topic for all versions and marked appropriately?

Subquestion: If they should be moved, why do topics have versions at all since examples that don't belong to all versions could be marked appropriately and kept in the all versions topic.

Comment: I asked this question *many hours ago* as a proposed "improvements needed", but apparently someone "dismissed" that because they disagreed. And since there's no record (that I can find) of dismissed "improvements needed", one person has a binding, unanimous vote. It will not scale well if we have to go to Meta for Every. Single. Little. Detailed. Question. that we have about how to organize docs.

Comment: @CodyGray here it is http://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray?tab=documentation&sort=requestsforimprovement

Comment: @Braiam Hmm, okay, thanks. Hadn't noticed that new section of my profile. But when I click on those, I still can't see what my actual proposal was. It's just a record that I did *something*.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, that is apparently the expected behavior [Dismissed improvement request are deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328646)